# Load html with javascript issue in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm struggling on this question for whole day, so maybe someone could help.

I want to load settings.php page, which includes javascript/jquery code with usual html, into index.php on button click.

Here are the code snippets:

Index.php

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadSettingsPage (){
        $('#myResults').load('settings.php', function (){ });
        }
</script>
</head>
```

Settings.php

```
<div class="tabsWrapper">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data="sections" onclick="setTab('sections')">Product categories</li>
    <li data="suppliers" onclick="setTab('suppliers')">Suppliers</li>
</ul>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function setTab(currentTab = "sections"){
//some code goes here
};

$(document).ready(function (){
//document ready code goes here with click events
}
</script>
```

The question is, how to load/include Settings.php file into index.php file so that all javascript code included click events in $(document).ready function is executed in safari browser as well. Now it works perfectly with all browsers but safari.

Comment: Could you just `include('settings.php')` inside of your HTML myResults element.

Comment: Not an option, I want to load settings.php dynamically. I could load it, hide and then onclick appear, but I have bunch of other files which should be included/removed into myResults div according to click.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to use the EcmaScript 6 feature of default parameters. This isn't yet implemented in Safari, Opera, or Internet Explorer, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Use an explicit check for whether the argument is set:

```
function setTab(currentTab) {
    currentTab = currentTab || "sections";
    // some code goes here
}
```

You need to be very careful about using new ES6 features, many of them are not yet implemented in Safari, and they'll never be implemented in old IE versions.

Comment: I was writing the same answer just not as good, quickly hit the delete button plus 1.

Comment: Okay, I will fix this, but the main problem is still alive

Comment: This seems like the main problem to me. You were getting a syntax error, so the code didn't run. Are you still getting errors? What does it say in the Javascript console?

Comment: OMG I get tones of errors and warnings, it will take lots of time to fix them all (( Why does safari behave so stupidly and different way from all other browsers

Comment: I suspect you're using other ES6 features. These are new, and they haven't been added to Safari yet.

Comment: You should probably bookmark caniuse.com to see what features are incompatible between browsers.